# Getting error "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file .... failed."

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, windows

I am creating a database based application. I have created a solution which contains 2 projects

1) Windows forms application

2) Datalayer - where i have added a sql server database to a folder.

I know that its something related to path but i am not able to figure it out.

[image]

This is the app.config of datalayer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BillingKioskDatalayer.Properties.Settings.BillingDBConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\BillingDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I added 'User Instance=True' ran the solution again and got the same exception.

> "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   E:\XGHProjects\BillingKiosk\BillingKiosk\bin\Debug\DB\BillingDB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Below is the property window of the db file.

[image]

Initially it was getting copied in the billingkiosk's debug folder but then i updated "Copy to output directory property  to Do Not Copy.
I have been through following links :

http://forums.asp.net/t/956274.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6dfdcc22-7a81-4e8f-a947-c1ce6982d4b3/flustered-a-database-with-the-same-name-exists-or-specified-file-cannot-be-opened-or-it-is?forum=sqlexpress

["An attempt to attach an auto-named database" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466727/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-error)

[An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file **** failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622299/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-failed)

[An Attempt to attach an auto-named database Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509441/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-error)

Do i need to change the structure of the solution ?

Comment: Once I Face The same Problem But unfortunately I dont remember the solution.But IMHO You dont need to change the Structure it will solve with some trick.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Can't believe there are no answers posted below. I am facing the same problem and got here via Google Search results. Hope someone can post any solution to this problem.